# Check if and interceptor has been applied to a context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework context which inherits from ObjectContext and I am adding an interceptor to the same. But, the interceptor gets added multiple times. Is there a way to add the interceptor to the context only once while its being declared? Or as an alternative, is there a way to check if a context already has an interceptor attached to it?

Comment: What method are you using for adding interceptors?

Comment: I'm trying to add it using DbInterception.Add(new MyInterceptor(context))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you are using [DbInterception.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.dbinterception.add(v=vs.113).aspx) method to add interceptors.

Unfortunately there is no `Contains` method or any way to enumerate the interceptors.

The only way I see is to call [DbInterception.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.dbinterception.remove(v=vs.113).aspx) before adding the interceptor. But it will require your interceptors to override `Equals` method and compare by type or something else based on their content, i.e. compare by value rather than by reference.